# GCD - Block - Thread safe variable in loop

Tags: objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

Is `GKPlayer` player is safe inside for loop?

```
for (GKPlayer *player in players) {
  [player loadPhotoForSize:GKPhotoSizeSmall withCompletionHandler:^(UIImage *photo, NSError *error) {
    if (!error && photo) {
      if ([player.playerID isEqualToString:[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].playerID]) {
        currentUser.image = photo;
      } else {
        otherUser.image = photo;
      }
    }
  }];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

YES (assuming your code is only executed in main thread)

from [Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKPlayer_Ref/Reference/Reference.html)

> When this method is called, it creates a new background task to handle the request. The method then returns control to your game. Later, when the task is complete, Game Kit calls your completion handler. **The completion handler is always called on the main thread.**

Your code is only executed in main thread so no thread-safety issue.

---

A possible execution sequence of your code is something like this

```
[player1 loadPhotoForSize...];
[player2 loadPhotoForSize...];
[player3 loadPhotoForSize...];

// method return

// photo for player3 downloaded
completionHandlerForPlayer3(photo, error);

// photo for player1 downloaded
completionHandlerForPlayer1(photo, error);

// photo for player1 downloaded
completionHandlerForPlayer2(photo, error);
```

Everything happened on main thread, it is not possible to have threading issue.

Comment: I am not asking about `loadPhotoForSize`, but how for loop affects `player` variable

Comment: @com.iavian what do you mean? the only thing in loop is `loadPhotoForSize`

Comment: variable 'player' is in a loop. What happens when first call loop [`loadPhotoForSize`]completes after second call is called?